# Mongo DB Array of objects lookup on another collection

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

So problem is that i have an array of object in every document (comments field) of my Posts collection. Every object has a property "commentAuthorId". Thing i wan't to do is perform a lookup on every object in comments array and insert into that object information about comment author based on mentioned before "commentAuthorId". User info is in another collection called "Users". 
Here is what I tried so far and it's not working.

```
    {
      $unwind: '$comments'
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Users",
        localField: "comments.commentAuthorId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "commentAuthorDetails",
      },
    },
    {$group: {  
      _id: "$_id",
      comments: {
        $push: {
            _id: "$comments._id",
            authorDetails: "$commentAuthorDetails"
        }
      }
    }
```

Document example - Posts:

```
 {
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5eb2ed9f4c53d52b8c69f01b"
   },
   "createdBy":"5e45bf41e2465801801455d9",
   "postContent":"dasdsa\n#lazyloadingtest\n      ",
   "tags":[
      "lazyloadingtest"
   ],
   "addedAt":{
      "$date":"2020-05-06T17:02:23.138Z"
   },
   "likes":[

   ],
   "likesCount":0,
   "comments":[
      {
         "content":"afdsfsdf",
         "author":"Kacper",
         "postId":"5eb2ed9f4c53d52b8c69f01b",
         "commentAuthorId":"5e45bf41e2465801801455d9",
         "addedAt":{
            "$date":"2020-05-06T17:02:25.167Z"
         },
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"5eb2eda14c53d52b8c69f01c"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Document example - User:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5e45bf41e2465801801455d9"
   },
   "name":"Kacper",
   "email":"kacper@kacper.pl",
   "password":"$2b$12$QeCw0AKlRI1kjAJc6eM5hOvxc5gRk/FhuI9vDcGLitsrSkHQZp8ky",
   "userPicture":null
}
```

Expected lookup aggregation result:

```
{
  "_id":{
     "$oid":"5eb2ed9f4c53d52b8c69f01b"
  },
  "createdBy":"5e45bf41e2465801801455d9",
  "postContent":"dasdsa\n#lazyloadingtest\n      ",
  "tags":[
     "lazyloadingtest"
  ],
  "addedAt":{
     "$date":"2020-05-06T17:02:23.138Z"
  },
  "likes":[

  ],
  "likesCount":0,
  "comments":[
     {
        "content":"afdsfsdf",
        "author":"Kacper",
        "postId":"5eb2ed9f4c53d52b8c69f01b",
        "commentAuthorId":"5e45bf41e2465801801455d9",
        "addedAt":{
           "$date":"2020-05-06T17:02:25.167Z"
        },
        "_id":{
           "$oid":"5eb2eda14c53d52b8c69f01c"
        },
        "postAuthorInfo": {
          "_id":{
             "$oid":"5e45bf41e2465801801455d9"
          },
          "name":"Kacper",
          "email":"kacper@kacper.pl",
          "password":"$2b$12$QeCw0AKlRI1kjAJc6eM5hOvxc5gRk/FhuI9vDcGLitsrSkHQZp8ky",
          "userPicture":null
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

There is only one comment but i wan't to do this lookup for every next comment basend on "commentAuthorId" field.

Comment: please share sample documents. And the required output.

Comment: I'll updated question with sample documents and required output.